# Google maps markerOptions size

Tags: java, android, dictionary, marker, code-snippets

I'm trying to increase the size of a google markerOptions because the text inside is not totally visible...

This is my code, i didn't find an option to set the size.

```
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //Normalement on va devoir boucler sur toutes les coordonnées reçu pour créer tous les markers
    googleMap
            .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(50.200323, 4.897113))
                    .title("Collecte de Falmagne")
                    .snippet("Horaires de cette collecte : \n Lundi : 10H00-15H00 \n Mardi 13H00-17H00 \n Mercredi 8H00-12H00")
                    );
```

And this is an image to show what is my problem

[image]

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english !

Comment: the marker or the info window?

Comment: @armen the info window, i want to see all the text inside the info window

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to change the size of marker in Google maps.. but we can add a custom image or from Bitmap...

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.marker); Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap(); Bitmap ***marker*** = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 200, 400, false);

googleMap .addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(new LatLng(50.200323, 4.897113)) .title("Collecte de Falmagne") .icon(***marker***) .snippet("Horaires de cette collecte : ));
```

Comment: Thank you i'm going to test this !

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a Layout and add it to a Custom InfoWindowAdapter.

custom_info_window.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blank"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Add the custom adapter inside your Activity/Fragment Map:

```
 private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
     @Override
     public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        TextView tvSubTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle);

        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        tvSubTitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());
        return view;
     }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks i'm going to try this today if the other solutions don't work ;)